# Как нормализовать координаты для ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

При индексации данных ElasticSearch выплевывает ошибку:

`{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"illegal latitude value [129.77067] for coordinates"}}`

Ему не нравятся данные с такими координатами:

`"longitude" => "62.09325"
"latitude" => "129.77067"`

Координаты существуют: Yakutsk Airport:  Tiganos: 62.09325°N 129.77067°

https://ceb.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakutsk_Airport

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно скормить такие координаты эластику?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо, перепутаны широта (latitude, юг -90, север +90 градусов) и долгота (longitude, от -180 до 180 градусов с запада на восток с нулев в Гринвиче).

Comment: хм, данные из геонеймс. спасибо, перепроверю.

Comment: оказалось, что действительно перепутаны координаты